# Recode same factor levels values among multiple variables "with mutate_at" in Tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, forcats

I have several factor variables with values "1" and "2" that need to be recoded to "Yes" and "No". Tidyverse *mutate_at* with *fct_recode* appear to be the right tools. However,

```
dataframe %>%
 mutate_at(vars (var1, var9, var17) =
              fct_recode(vars(var1, var9, var17), 
                         "Yes" = "1",
                         "No" = "2"))
```

gives

```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"                         "Yes" = "1",
                         "No" = "2"))"
```

And,

```
dataframe %>%
 mutate_at(vars (var1, var9, var17), 
              funs(fct_recode(vars(var1, var9, var17), 
                         "Yes" = "1",
                         "No" = "2")))
```

gives

```
Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector).
```

Can someone point at my mistake or do I use *mutate_at*, *vars* or *fct_recode* wrong? Is there a better way in tidyverse to recode same factor levels on multiple variables, a very common task in tidying data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your syntax in `mutate_at()`.

```
library(dplyr)
```

First, I create a sample dataset:

```
set.seed(666)
dataframe <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c("1", "2"), 5, replace = TRUE),
                        var9 = sample(c("1", "2"), 5, replace = TRUE),
                        var17 = sample(c("1", "2"), 5, replace = TRUE))

  var1 var9 var17
1    2    2     2
2    1    2     1
3    2    1     1
4    1    1     1
5    1    1     1
```

Then I use `mutate_at()` like this: `.vars` are unchanged, but `.funs` is only the function, additional parameter to `funs` are passed in `...`:

```
dataframe %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(var1, var9, var17),
            .funs = forcats::fct_recode,
            "Yes" = "1",
            "No" = "2")
```

The end result:

```
  var1 var9 var17
1   No   No    No
2  Yes   No   Yes
3   No  Yes   Yes
4  Yes  Yes   Yes
5  Yes  Yes   Yes
```